# Multiple COUNT SELECTS from the same table in one query

Tags: sql-server, select

For some people it might look very simple, but I just simply can't get it.
I have multiple MS-SQL SELECT queries from the same table over and over:

```
SELECT count(Page) as tAEC
FROM someTable
WHERE Page LIKE '%AEC%'
```

next one

```
SELECT count(Page) as tTOL
FROM someTable
WHERE Page LIKE '%TOL%'
```

and so on...

What would be more efficient way to write this query. I Googled bunch of similar questions but I couldnt make any of them to work. So any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(case when Page LIKE '%AEC%' then 1 end) as tAEC, 
    sum(case when Page LIKE '%TOL%' then 1 end) as tTOL 
FROM someTable
```

Comment: Nice, thank you very much. I'v tried similar `sum(case` query, but now I see what I was doing wrong. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have multiple columns in the same table, and I want to make sure it selects only `Page` column. Is that what it does?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Providing sample data and desired output would help.

Comment: Sorry. I have many columns in the table `id` `Page` `Facility` etc.. with over 6 million row records. So I just want to make sure I only select `Page` column for query. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, this query only examines the `Page` column. It does not select it, it selects counts.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `GROUP BY Page`

```
SELECT
  Page
, COUNT(Page) as "nb"
FROM someTable
GROUP BY Page
```

You can also do a `GROUP BY CASE...`

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN Page LIKE '%AEC%' THEN "AEC"
    WHEN Page LIKE '%TOL%' THEN "TOL"
    ELSE ""
  END AS "type"
, count(Page) as "nb"
FROM someTable
GROUP BY type
```

You can also `COUNT IF`

```
SELECT
  COUNT(IF(Page LIKE '%AEC%', 1, NULL) THEN "AEC"
, COUNT(IF(Page LIKE '%TOL%', 1, NULL) THEN "TOL"
FROM someTable
```