# SQL Server: multiple select statements from the same table in one query

Tags: sql-server, join, count

I'm working on two queries that pull data from one table. I can get them to run how I want individually, but I'd like to combine them into one if possible. I've tried the solution in [[Multiple COUNT SELECTS from the same table in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938332/multiple-count-selects-from-the-same-table-in-one-query][1]) but wasn't able to get it figured out. Below is what I'm working on:

```
--goback 30 days start at midnight
declare @daysgoingback as int
set @daysgoingback = 90

declare @olderdate as datetime
set @olderdate = DATEADD(Day, -@daysgoingback, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GetDate()))

--today at 11:59pm
declare @today as datetime
set @today = dateadd(ms, -3, (dateadd(day, +1, convert(varchar, GETDATE(), 101))))
print @today

--these are the two queries I'd like to combine:
select 
    avg(x.LogAlerts*1.0 / @daysgoingback) as 'Avg number of log alerts'
from
    (select count(*) as LogAlerts 
     from message_log_table 
     where msg_timestamp between @olderdate and @today) X

select 
    avg(x.MessagesDeleted*1.0 / @daysgoingback) as 'Avg number of messages deleted'
from
    (select count(*) as MessagesDeleted 
     from message_log_table 
     where msg_details like '%message deleted%' 
       and msg_timestamp between @olderdate and @today) X
```

Comment: Combine them how?   one on top of the other?   side-by-side?

Comment: @TabAlleman I'd like to combine them in the sense that MSSQL runs it as one query and returns the results side by side as if I just selected a couple of columns from a table.

Comment: Be careful here. You are doing some funky date math so you can use between. If you change the datatype to datetime2 your query is no longer as accurate. Between can be really problematic, especially when it comes to dates. https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"AVG" is an aggregate function, which averages multiple rows.  Your "select count(*)" subquery always returns exactly one row, so you are not really using the AVG function as it's intended.

You can combine the two like this:

```
   select   count(*) * 1.0 / @daysgoingback as 'Avg number of log alerts'
            , count(case when msg_details like '%message deleted%' then 1 end) * 1.0 / @daysgoingback as 'Avg number of messages deleted'
    from    message_log_table 
    where   msg_timestamp between @olderdate and @today;
```

Comment: I didn't realize I was using AVG incorrectly, so thank you for pointing that out. I tried your query as well, and it works exactly how I'd like it to. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Make each query into a CTE, and then CROSS JOIN them.

Both queries only return a single-cell result, so there's no need to get fancy here.